# Docusign Resend with REST

Tags: c#, docusignapi

So there is another ticket here (closed) that talks about how to do this.  However, something must have changed since that ticket was answered.
I followed the very sparse documentation at DocuSign, and keep getting stuck.
I followed another ticket here exactly, and I'm still getting an error that I can't resolve.  I do have dozens of different types of calls working perfectly, this is the only call (so far) that I have tried that I can't get to work.

I have a recipient that lost their email.  I need to resend to them.  No changes to the document are necessary.

I do a 'PUT' to the following URL:
[https://na4.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{Redacted}/envelopes/{Redacted}/recipients?resend_envelope=true](https://na4.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/%7BRedacted%7D/envelopes/%7BRedacted%7D/recipients?resend_envelope=true)

In the body, I pass the object 'DocuSign.eSign.Model.Recipients'
There is 1 recipient, the one who lost the email.  (again, status is 'sent', I checked manually to be sure).   I included it below for sake of documentation.

I get the following error.  I cannot get past this.  The error sounds obvious.  It sounds like the recipient document is in a status that cannot be resent, but that's simply not the case.  I've verified the status, I've verified that account # is correct, I've verified that document id and recipient id are correct.  Just not sure what else I can check.

I just need to resend this, and this call should be the right call.  According to the documentation, 'PUT' is the correct verb.

```
{
    "recipientUpdateResults": [
        {
            "recipientId": "1",
            "errorDetails": {
                "errorCode": "RECIPIENT_UPDATE_FAILED",
                "message": "The recipient could not be updated.
                    Recipient not in state that allows correction."
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Body of document that is being sent.  I've tried both with emailBody & emailSubject NULL, or the original values.  Neither way works.

```
{
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "{Redacted}",
            "emailNotification": {
                "emailBody": "{Redacted}",
                "emailSubject": "{Redacted}"
            },
            "name": "{Redacted}",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "dateSignedTabs": [
                    {
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "xPosition": "60",
                        "yPosition": "757"
                    }
                ],
                "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                        "documentId": "1",
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "xPosition": "50",
                        "yPosition": "652"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the envelope was already sent, meaning it's not longer in "draft" status you cannot simply modify it anymore.
Envelopes can be modified at will only when they are in "draft" state and if your envelope was in that state - you wouldn't get this error.

Once the envelope was sent ("sent" state) you need to use special **Correct** action for any changes. That can be initiated by putting envelope into correct state and potentially giving user the correct view where they can add/remove recipients and tags.

**Update:** If you are just trying to resend the envelope, make sure the JSON body of your request is empty ({}). Empty object in C# will do the trick...

**Update 2:** Need to use REST API v2.1 and not v2.0.

Comment: So if the user says they never got the email, and I need to resend it to them, I have to 'correct' it, even though nothing is wrong with it.
And when I correct it, then I can resend it?

So I'll just correct it by adding 1 space to the end of the body, and send it?

Comment: When I look at the API, the 'correct' can only be done to a 'draft', and cannot be done to a 'sent'.  On the contrary, the call that I am using with the 'resend_envelope=true' does read like that should be the call I use.

I apologize, I must be mis-reading your advice.  Because the documentation is very clear that the update can only be done on a draft.

Comment: You don't need to "correct" to send another email. But you cannot make an API call to change anything either.

Comment: Are you merely trying to send an email again about your envelope? or are you trying to modify the envelope? I'm really not clear on that.

Comment: If you just want to send another email, make sure the body is empty. Don't put anything in it.

Comment: I've been experimenting with this for days.   I put nothing, other than email address in, and still the same error.

Comment: Do you use an SDK? C#? can you share the code you use?

Comment: The JSON you have in the question is wrong.

Comment: How is the json wrong?  I pulled that right out of the REST documentation?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to update the envelope? or are you trying to simply resend an email?

Comment: I simply want to re-send it.   The recipient says they never got it, I need to send it to them again, no changes of any type are needed.
I've tried with a body of this: {} tells me I need at least 1 recipient.

I've tried with a body of this:
{"signers":[{"email":"email@whatever.com","name":"Brian","recipientId":"1"}]}

The recipient '1' does match the original document.  Still doesn't work.  Tells me the recipient is not in the correct state.

Comment: Please share the API logs, I just tried this with body {} and got no error, so you're doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. You may need to contact customer support.

Comment: Where would I get logs?  I am doing a WebRequest, there would be no logs?
This URL (is something wrong here?)
{BaseURL}/restapi/v2/accounts/{AccountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients?resend_envelope=true
I do a WebRequest PUT, with a 2 byte body {}
I get a '400 bad request'
This is the body back from docusign:
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. No recipients specified."
}

Comment: You are using API v2, I was using v2.1. May want to try to use v2.1

Comment: Also, the JSON body should be {} completely empty body, nothing in there.

Comment: Wow.  The 2.1 fixed it!   No other changes were necessary.  so that's all it was all along, I just needed to bump to the next version.
Inbar, I want to thank you so much, you have been super helpful.

Comment: I'll update the answer to that effect. Happy to help.